How to solve ERROR: daal4py 2021.5.0 requires daal==2021.4.0, which is not installed?
I try to install sklearn package and getting the warning below:
> File D:\ANACONDA\envs\TenserFlow\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_svdp.py:24     
       from ._propack import _spropack  # type: ignore[attr-defined]  

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _spropack: The specified procedure could not be found.   

Then, I try to upgrade scipy but still get error below:
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
daal4py 2021.5.0 requires daal==2021.4.0, which is not installed.
numba 0.55.1 requires numpy<1.22,>=1.18, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.

How can I solve this warning and error?
My code:
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


pip install daal==2021.4.0 and also a valid version of numpy as per the error message.
